# Add a icon in the title

Tags: django

How to add a icon in the Title of a website?
I have tried to find a html-specific way, but I didn't find any html-tag in the "`<title>`"

```
{% block title %}
    <title> 
        text of the title
    </title>
{% endblock %}
```

How to add a picture?

Comment: I think you are referring to the _favicon_ aren't you?

Comment: yes I want to add a favicon. Now I know the right name of this icon

Comment: Seriously.....? GOOGLE IT. https://www.google.ca/search?q=icon+in+title+bar+of+web+page&oq=icon+in+title&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.6687j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve Favicon for django Urls it slef

Try this

```
 (r'^favicon\.ico$', 
     'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', 
     {'url': '/media/favicon.ico'}),
```

and more [options here](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/774/create-an-icon-for-a-django-app)

Comment: this don't work for me. I found a working option in your link thx